# The image of the element of $Z(G)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

For a group $G$, the definition of its centre is given by $Z(G)=\{a\in G\mid ag=ga,\forall g\in G\}$

Let $$\varphi : G \longrightarrow GL(V) $$ be an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$, with $V$ a finite dimensional linear space over $\mathbb{C}$.

How can I prove that the image of the elements of $Z(G)$ under $\varphi$ all have the form $\lambda I$?  Here $I$ is the unit matrix in $GL(V)$ and $\lambda \neq 0$.

I know that a matrix $A$ which commutes with every matrix $\varphi(g)$, for $g\in G$, must  have the form $\lambda I$. However the image of general $g\in G$ under $\varphi$ need only be an invertible matrix in general.  Why must the elements of $\varphi(Z(G))$ be of the form $\lambda I$?

Thank you for sharing your mind.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Specifically, show your work and thoughts on the problem to improve your chances of getting help, otherwise your question will be downvoted.

Comment: Well, did you try to assume that the image of some central element has at least two different eigenspaces? And remember, the representation is irreducible.

Comment: Given that the OP has now added what they were thinking (which is almost a complete solution) and I have cleaned up the grammar, I do not think the downvotes are necessary any more.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there.  From the definition of centre, we know that if $a\in Z(G)$ then $ag=ga$ for any $g\in G$.  Apply $\varphi$ and we see that $$\varphi(a)\varphi(g)=\varphi(g)\varphi(a).$$

That is the matrix $\varphi(a)$ satisfies the condition you mentioned in the question: it commutes with all $\varphi(g)$, with $g\in G$.

You said you already knew that this condition implies that $\varphi(a)=\lambda I$.